# Check if user exists in passport-local

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have an Express app with the passport-local strategy, using Mongoose for storing user Accounts. I had a freelancer write this part of the app for me because I couldn't make sense of how to build the login system from beginning to end (every single tutorial I found did it in a different way). The drawback of this is that I don't understand what each part does. This is in my `app.js` file:

```
const Account = require('./models/db/AccountsSchema');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());
```

and this is in `routes/index.js`:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    Account.register(new Account({
        username: req.body.username,
        name: req.body.name
    }), req.body.password, function(err, account) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(account);
            passport.authenticate('local', {
                successRedirect: '/',
                failureRedirect: '/login'
            })(req, res, function(err, user) {
                res.redirect('/');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

along with:

```
router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local'),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

Now in the login POST request I want to have a check for whether a user with that particular username exists, so that if the password is wrong at least I can tell the user that the password is wrong. User enumeration is not a security concern here.

Where in my code can I incorporate a database check for whether an Account with the specified username exists?

Answer (score 0):

In `Account.authenticate()` function. As it sets the LocalStrategy in your case.

setting your local strategy:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
```

Sample Code:

```
function authenticate(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I don't see where user.validPassword() comes from. Is that a passport.js function?

Comment: @Ric not it's not a passport.js function, but custom model functions defined in mongoose schema.